# How to iterate through javascirpt array with a sleep/delay?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am trying to set  view & marker at one geo location and after a delay/sleep set the marker in another location. I'm using leaflet.js. There is a data array

```
[
    {
        "city": "City_1",
        "lat": 8.702127234287211,
        "lon": 77.1684975438538,
        "temp": 25,
        "icon": ""
    },
    {
        "city": "City_2",
        "lat": 9.083099761723636, 
        "lon": 74.81806072890778, 
        "temp": 0,
        "icon": ""
    }
]
```

and on button click the data is read and looped. Tried `setInterval()` with no success.

```
const startUpdating = async () => {    
    const response = await fetch('data.json');
    const data = await response.json();
    const marker = L.marker();// init marker

    for (i of data) {
        // Tried setInterval(setView, 1000); // no success.
        await map.setView([i.lat, i.lon], 10);
        marker.setLatLng([i.lat, i.lon]).addTo(map);
    }
}
startBtn.addEventListener('click', startUpdating);
```

So how to set a delay so that data is read from array, set the marker and view on map, wait for some time and then again iterate.

Comment: What does it look like now? Only one marker appear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fortunately, you are already in an `async` context. `setTimeout` is easy to promisify:

```
function delay(time) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, time));
}
```

Then simply insert `await delay(1000)` to wait for one second.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of looping it with a for loop, you can drain your data array using a recursive function call with a setTimeout which should pretty much look like this.

```
const response = await fetch('data.json');
const data = await response.json();
// ... some other codes
const setNext = () => {
  if (data.length) {
    const item = data.shift();
    // ... set you marker here    
  }

  if (data.length) {
    setTimeout(setNext, 1000);
  }
};
setNext();
```